# How to list all allowed actions I can perform in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

I've been granted access to a k8s cluster in k8s, and I'd like to see what privileges I have in the cluster, like creating/deleting pods and other such kind of actions. So far I know a command to check a particular action like:

```
kubectl auth can-i get pods
```

But could be good to see all the other commands, thus if someone knows it I'd appreciate sharing it with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply run:

```
kubectl auth can-i --list
```

According to the help:

```
kubectl auth can-i --help


--list=false:
If true, prints all allowed actions.
```